# Bug when using Offlinebuilder in Liquidswipe

Tags: flutter

Hello I am using Offlinebuilder and Liquidswipe but it gives me a strange error someone knows how I can fix? thank you very much!

ERROR:

```
You should specify either a builder or a child
'package:flutter_offline/src/main.dart':
Failed assertion: line 41 pos 16: '!(builder is WidgetBuilder && child is Widget) && !(builder == null && child == null)'
```

```
class Luz extends State<MyApp> {
  ...
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    pages(bool connected) => [
      //pagina1
      Container(
       ...
      ),
      Container(
          color: Colors.pinkAccent[400],
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Align(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    alignment: Alignment(0, 0.3),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      width: 135,
                      height: 135,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1250),
                      curve: Curves.bounceOut,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          ...
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:Colors.purple[700].withOpacity(0.90),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                spreadRadius: 4,
                                blurRadius: 50,
                                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      left: 8,
                      right: 8,
                      top: 0,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.3),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 250,
                          height: 250,
                          child: (
                              Text(
                                'Luz desligada',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 28,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: WaveClipperOne(flip: true, reverse: true),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 120,
                      color: Colors.limeAccent[400],
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
            Positioned(
              left: 35,
              right: 35,
              top: connected ? -1000 : 175,
              child: GestureDetector(
                /*onTap: ()  async {
                  Navigator.push(
                  context,
                    PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                      child: MyApp()
                    )
                  );
                },*/
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  width: 250,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child:Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 250,
                      height: 111,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(27, 32, 27, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              'SEM INTERNET',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 1, 25, 30),
                            child: Text(
                              'RECONNECTCE',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        body: OfflineBuilder(
          connectivityBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          ConnectivityResult connectivity,
          Widget Container,
          ) {
            final bool connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
            return LiquidSwipe(
              pages: pages(connected),
              enableLoop: true,
              fullTransitionValue: 700,
              enableSlideIcon: false,
              waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
              positionSlideIcon: 0.7,
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In OfflineBuilder you must have pass a chilld widget or builder function args. Try pass: 

```child: Container()```

Comment: Hello but where do I put ```child: Container()``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: change `Widget Container` to `Widget child` 
Step 2: You can use `builder` of `OfflineBuilder` and use `Stack` in `connectivityBuilder`

code snippet

```
  bool connected;

  return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: OfflineBuilder(
      connectivityBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        ConnectivityResult connectivity,
        Widget child,
      ) {
        connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
        print(connected);
        return Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            child,
            Positioned(
              height: 32.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                color: connected ? Color(0xFF00EE44) : Color(0xFFEE4400),
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                  child: connected
                      ? Text('ONLINE')
                      : Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('OFFLINE'),
                            SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 12.0,
                              height: 12.0,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                                valueColor:
                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return LiquidSwipe(
          pages: pages(connected),
          fullTransitionValue: 200,
          enableSlideIcon: true,
          enableLoop: true,
          positionSlideIcon: 0.5,
          currentUpdateTypeCallback: updateTypeCallback,
          waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
        );
      },
    )));
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'package:flutter_offline/flutter_offline.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static final style = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: "Billy",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  );

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int page = 0;

  UpdateType updateType;

  List<Container> pages(bool connected) => [
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/500?image=14',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Hi",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "It's Me",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Sahdeep",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/500?image=13',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Take a",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "look at",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Liquid Swipe",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/500?image=11',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Liked?",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Fork!",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Give Star!",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellowAccent,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/500?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Can be",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Used for",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Onboarding Design",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/500?image=10',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Do",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Try it",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Thank You",
                    style: MyApp.style,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ];

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((page ?? 0) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    double zoom = 1.0 + (2.0 - 1.0) * selectedness;
    return Container(
      width: 25.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: Container(
            width: 8.0 * zoom,
            height: 8.0 * zoom,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool connected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: OfflineBuilder(
      connectivityBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        ConnectivityResult connectivity,
        Widget child,
      ) {
        connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
        print(connected);
        return Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            child,
            Positioned(
              height: 32.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                color: connected ? Color(0xFF00EE44) : Color(0xFFEE4400),
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                  child: connected
                      ? Text('ONLINE')
                      : Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('OFFLINE'),
                            SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 12.0,
                              height: 12.0,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                                valueColor:
                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return LiquidSwipe(
          pages: pages(connected),
          fullTransitionValue: 200,
          enableSlideIcon: true,
          enableLoop: true,
          positionSlideIcon: 0.5,
          currentUpdateTypeCallback: updateTypeCallback,
          waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
        );
      },
    )));
  }

  updateTypeCallback(UpdateType updateType) {
    print(updateType);
  }
}
```